# Crashlytics react native errors in javascript filname not mentioned

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am using crashlytics with react native :

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.2",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.9.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",
```

I have followed instructions to integrate crashlytics with react native app following these instructions ( [here](https://aboutreact.com/integrate-firebase-in-android-and-ios-app/) and [here](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/android-setup)
Tried simulating an error but in crashlytics it shows without the actual react native class name from which this error originates

[image]

How do I get the logs to show javascript file name along with line number ?
NOTE :
proguard-rules file has the following entry :

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: no unfortunately none